# Recursive make in subdirectories

Tags: recursion, directory, makefile, subdirectory

How can I order `make` command in the Makefile to execute recursively in all subdirectories `make` commands (defined in the Makefile in the subdirectories)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1. Read **[Recursive Use of Make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Recursion)** chapter of GNU Make manual.
2. Learn Peter Miller's **[Recursive Make Considered Harmful](https://web.archive.org/http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf)** article.
3. ...
4. **PROFIT!!!**

---

P.S. A code snippet from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11206700/545027) to a different yet related question could be used as a rough approximation.

Comment: @Mali that's worth reading, certainly! I have experimented a bit on this topic long time ago too, FYI: http://abusalimov.blogspot.ru/2009/12/yet-another-implementation-of-non.html

Comment: @wil93 thank you for the proposed edit! I added a link to another answer that suggest a solution similar to yours.

Comment: The Miller article seriously proposes as a solution to the problem of "I have a module shared between projects" to "combine the projects into one"?  That is patently absurd.  Just because I want to include a snapshot of some third-party code as a submodule in my repository does not mean I want to coordinate development with them.

Comment: The approach in this answer is totally unusable for managing multiple dependencies. If I have one application that depends on 3 libraries with complicated makefiles, how am I supposed to combine them into one? That's impossible to maintain.

Comment: @Quimby I guess, you're right, and this is indeed more about building a single project organized into multiple directories rather than build dependent project.

Comment: The Make Gods have landed!

Answer (score 9):

@eldar-abusalimov, the first link you posted assumes the makefile **knows** what are the subfolders. This is not always true, and I guess thats what @tyranitar would like to know. In that case, such a solution can do the job:
(took me some time, but I needed it too)

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

all:
    @for a in $$(ls); do \
        if [ -d $$a ]; then \
            echo "processing folder $$a"; \
            $(MAKE) -C $$a; \
        fi; \
    done;
    @echo "Done!"
```

Comment: It could be achieved in pure Make: `SUBDIRS := $(wildcard */.)`. And then iterating over `SUBDIRS` and invoking a sub-make.

Comment: @Eldar Abusalimov : Sounds nice. I'm interested, could you detail a bit more and post sample make snippet ? (What do you mean by 'iterating' ?)

Comment: I mean using a solution, which I have proposed in my another answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11206700/545027

Answer (score 7):

The above answers work well when all of the subdirectories have Makefiles. It is not that difficult to only run make on the directories that contain Makefile, nor is it difficult to restrict the number of levels to recurse. In my sample code, I restrict the search for makefiles to the subdirectories immediately below the parent directory. The filter-out statement (line 2) prevents this Makefile from being included in the recursive makes.

```
MAKEFILES = $(shell find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -name Makefile)
SUBDIRS   = $(filter-out ./,$(dir $(MAKEFILES)))

all:
    for dir in $(SUBDIRS); do \
        make -C $$dir all; \
    done
```

Comment: You could use  the `-mindepth` option of the find command to filter out the root Makefile.

Comment: If you use `MAKEFILES` as a variable, make will go and parse all those files and complain if they have duplicate targets.  You should use a different variable name if that's not what you intend.

Comment: @NedBatchelder ++ your comment is to the point, thanks. Otherwise one can get this ```Makefile:24: warning: overriding recipe for target```

Answer (score 5):

I will submit here my particular solution.
Suppose we have a directory with many sub-directories, all of them with its own makefile:

```
root-dir\
    +----subdir1
    +----subdir2
    ...
    +----subdirn
```

then, just copy in the root-dir this Makefile:

```
SUBDIRS = $(shell ls -d */)
all:
    for dir in $(SUBDIRS) ; do \
        make -C  $$dir ; \
    done
```

Comment: This might do the job but is sub-optimal. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11206700/272735 and https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recursion.html#Recursion for the "correct" approach.