# Compile several projects (with makefile), but stop on first broken build?

Tags: bash, makefile

I want to do *something* like:

```
for i in *
do
    if test -d $i
    then
        cd $i; make clean; make; cd -;
    fi;
done
```

And this works fine, but I want "break" the `for`-loop in case of a broken build.

Is there a way to do this? Maybe some kind of `if`-statement, that can check for success of `make`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check whether the `make` has exited successfully by examining its exit code via the `$?` variable, and then have a `break` statement:

```
...
make

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    break
fi
```

Comment: With improved rhyming: `for i in *; do make $i || break; done`

Answer (score 21):

You can use Make itself to achieve what you're looking for:

```
SUBDIRS := $(wildcard */.)

.PHONY : all $(SUBDIRS)
all : $(SUBDIRS)

$(SUBDIRS) :
    $(MAKE) -C $@ clean all
```

Make will break execution in case when any of your target fails.

### UPD.

To support arbitrary targets:

```
SUBDIRS := $(wildcard */.)  # e.g. "foo/. bar/."
TARGETS := all clean  # whatever else, but must not contain '/'

# foo/.all bar/.all foo/.clean bar/.clean
SUBDIRS_TARGETS := \
    $(foreach t,$(TARGETS),$(addsuffix $t,$(SUBDIRS)))

.PHONY : $(TARGETS) $(SUBDIRS_TARGETS)

# static pattern rule, expands into:
# all clean : % : foo/.% bar/.%
$(TARGETS) : % : $(addsuffix %,$(SUBDIRS))
    @echo 'Done "$*" target'

# here, for foo/.all:
#   $(@D) is foo
#   $(@F) is .all, with leading period
#   $(@F:.%=%) is just all
$(SUBDIRS_TARGETS) :
    $(MAKE) -C $(@D) $(@F:.%=%)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'll stick with the `if`-statement, as I don't want to create new makefile or edit the existing ones.

Comment: @Kiril, in fact you can use, e.g., heredoc to redirect the code to make, thus eliminating the need to create a Makefile. `make -f - <<EOF ... EOF`.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Thanks! +1 for the effort.

Comment: How would one separate out the 'all' and 'clean' tasks so that a 'make clean' can be done at the top level? I've tried adding another target but, as it also depends on $(SUBDIRS) it does a make and make clean.

Comment: @Eldar thank you yes that does what I asked. I'll have to study it a bit to understand it but thank you.

Comment: @starfry I added some comments, hope they will help you to understand.

Comment: I get - `makefile:13: *** missing separator.  Stop.`

Comment: @vishvAsvAsuki and any others with that issue, that is because when you copied and pasted, spaces were put in the Makefile instead of tabs.

Comment: Thanks! [Here](https://pastebin.com/raw/C0rrSYYU) is the same with TAB-s, which works

Comment: For anyone who might wonder what is `: % :`
https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html