# Running "make" in subdirectory: "No rule to make target"

Tags: gnu-make

I'm trying to get GNU Make to run some rules in subdirectories. The nutshell is: I have a project with multiple Python source directories (AWS lambdas), each with a pyproject.toml file, and the dependency installation managed by poetry. For each subdirectory, I need to install the packages mentioned in pyproject.toml, which creates a poetry.lock file, which is then used to produce a requirements.txt file (which gets deployed to AWS and used there).

Here's what I've got so far:

```
POETRY := $(shell command -v poetry 2> /dev/null)
PY_LAMBDAS := $(dir $(wildcard src/python/*/pyproject.toml))

.PHONY: $(PY_LAMBDAS)

install-py-lambdas : $(PY_LAMBDAS)

$(PY_LAMBDAS) :
     $(MAKE) -C $@ requirements.txt

requirements.txt : poetry.lock
     $(POETRY) export --without-hashes --format=requirements.txt > requirements.txt

# Ignore for now
# poetry.lock : pyproject.toml
#   $(POETRY) install

# pyproject.toml : | $(VENV)/bin/python
#   $(PY8) -m venv $(VENV)
```

If a lambda directory has a `requirements.txt` file in it, it says `Nothing to be done for 'requirements.txt'`, which seems fine. If there's no `requirements.txt` file, it errors with: `No rule to make target 'requirements.txt'.  Stop.`  As I'm testing right now, the `poetry.lock` file is already present in all directories.

My best guess is that the fact that the rule is running in a subdirectory is causing some kind of failure to find the target and rule, I have no idea. I need to run the rule in the subdirectory, because poetry reads its environment from the current directory, and doesn't have any sort of "target directory" option.

I'm hoping this is a relatively simple mistake on my part! Any alternate solutions to my basic issue would be very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is to have separate top-level Makefile that handles the recursion and sub-directory Makefiles that handle the actual build.

Relevant resources:

- GNU Make Manual: [Recursive Use of make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recursion.html#Recursion)
- One SO answer that shows [how to implement the recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11206700/272735)

Below you'll find a simplified example that should address your case. I don't know Python so I have replaced the Python related commands with simple commands but that should make no difference from Make point of view - this is a common Make pattern.

The directory structure:

```
$ exa --tree --long --no-permissions --no-user --no-time
  - .
  - ├── dir1
171 │  ├── Makefile
  0 │  └── pyproject.toml
  - ├── dir2
171 │  ├── Makefile
  0 │  └── pyproject.toml
187 └── Makefile
```

The top-level Makefile that handles the recursion and [passes the common variables to the sub-make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables_002fRecursion.html#Variables_002fRecursion):

```
$ cat Makefile 
export BUILD_COMMAND_1 = echo `date --iso-8601=seconds`
export BUILD_COMMAND_2 = cat

PROJECTS := $(wildcard dir?)

.PHONY: all $(PROJECTS)

all: $(PROJECTS)

$(PROJECTS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@
```

All subdirectories have identical Makefiles (here we just show `dir1/Makefile`):

```
$ cat dir1/Makefile
requirements.txt: poetry.lock
    $(BUILD_COMMAND_2) $< > $@

poetry.lock: pyproject.toml
    $(BUILD_COMMAND_1) > $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf poetry.lock requirements.txt
```

When the top-level Makefile is run first time all targets are built:

```
$ make
make -C dir1
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/t/dir1'
echo `date --iso-8601=seconds` > poetry.lock
cat poetry.lock > requirements.txt
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/t/dir1'
make -C dir2
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/t/dir2'
echo `date --iso-8601=seconds` > poetry.lock
cat poetry.lock > requirements.txt
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/t/dir2'
```

When the top-level Makefile is run second time and pre-requirements have not changed nothing needs to be built:

```
$ make
make -C dir1
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/t/dir1'
make[1]: 'requirements.txt' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/t/dir1'
make -C dir2
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/t/dir2'
make[1]: 'requirements.txt' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/t/dir2'
```

**A variation to pass a goal to sub-make**

- GNU Make Manual: [Arguments to Specify the Goals](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Goals.html)

The top-level Makefile:

```
$ cat Makefile 
export BUILD_COMMAND_1 = echo `date --iso-8601=seconds`
export BUILD_COMMAND_2 = cat

PROJECTS := $(wildcard dir?)

.PHONY: requirements.txt clean $(PROJECTS)

requirements.txt: $(PROJECTS)
clean: $(PROJECTS)

$(PROJECTS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@ $(MAKECMDGOALS)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had considered recursive Makefiles but thought there must be some easier way. The above has gotten me most of the way there: my only question is, how do I trigger the "clean" target in the subdirectory? Given that I've also got a "clean" target in the parent Makefile, how can I run the recursive "clean"s from there?

Comment: @girzel The recursive Makefiles are the easy way :) The answer has been updated to address also the second question raised in the comments.